# ASP - XSL creating href issues

Tags: xslt, asp-classic

I am very very new to ASP and im trying to setup a new email for a friend.

They have a xsl file which is the template for an email which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
Here is the text for the email, go to our website <a href="">here</a>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

They want to put in some dynamic values into the email, so i have entered the following

```
<a href="https://secure.website.com/page.asp?uid=<xsl:value-of select="email/userid"/>">Click here</a>
```

When i insert that, i keep getting errors, but when i use that code without the href tags, it displays fine.

If someone could help me out that would be great.

Cheers,

Comment: An XSLT file must itself be well formed XML, you can't put one tag inside an attribute of another. Search for "attribute value template" to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is this:

```
<a href="{email/userid}">
```

The salient point being that {...} points to the attribute or node value.

You could also try something like this:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">https://secure.website.com/page.asp?uid=<xsl:value-of select="email/userid" /></xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

make sure to not have whitespace inside the xsl:attribute tag.

Comment: Thanks for that, i tried the first one and it didnt work, im now trying the second example, but where to i enter the link description?

Comment: You can add it after the closing </xsl:attribute> tag.

Comment: Its printing the text, just not displaying it as a link, does it have anything to do with this line <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

Comment: I just put the word 'testing' behind the closing attribute tag ... when it comes through it just prints 'testing' and doesnt display it as a link